# Perl URL encoding .. problems with # in URL

Tags: perl, url-encoding

I have a URL that with spaces and `#` in it that I escape using `URI::Escape` to get the following.

https://copy.com/1rsdM7TvVcLfGebc/name%20with%20space%20and%20%23%20in%20it.jpg?

Note: In the original page from where I copied the above clicking the link doesn't work. The HTML from that page is shown here.

```
<a href=3D"https://copy.com/1rsdM7TvVcLfGebc/name%20with%20space%20and%20%23=
%20in%20it.jpg?source=3Dbsf" style=3D"color: white; font-weight: =
bold;">name with space and # in it.jpg</a>
```

As you can see `#` is correctly encoded as *%23*. The problem is when I click the link the browsers don't retain it as *%23* but encode it to `#` and prevent me from taking to the destination. This is how the link looks in the browser. You can see that after `#` the spaces are not rendered as *%20* either. The behavior is different in other browsers and none of them works.

https://www.copy.com/s/1rsdM7TvVcLfGebc/name%20with%20space%20and%20# in it.jpg

When I manually replace `#` with *%23* in the browser and push enter it correctly takes me to the page.

What's going on here?

Comment: why is there `3D` before the quotes? Otherwise the url looks fine.

Comment: This is [QP encoding](http://enwp.org/Quoted-printable) used in MIME, it looks like Mir neglected to properly [decode an email message](http://p3rl.org/Courriel).

Comment: The URI in the HTML snipped does not match the URI you're actually trying to reach, containing as it does extraneous spaces and =s.  As @daxim suggests, one of your previous transcoding steps was bungled.

Answer (score 1):

Not a Perl problem. The redirect on the Web host is broken! Compare:

- https://copy.com/1rsdM7TvVcLfGebc/name%20with%20space%20and%20%23%20in%20it.jpg?source=bsf
- https://copy.com/1rsdM7TvVcLfGebc/name%20with%20space%20and%20%23%20in%20it.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on its automatic URL encoding. You can force your URLs to encode/decode every time you need to use them.

You can use uri_escape() and  uri_unescape() functions for this purpose.